# Loading drivers from other modules in Code Igniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries, hmvc

I am using Code Igniters HMVC implementation by wiredesignz.

We have two modules, one for managing the actualy products/categories etc for a shopping cart, the other for managing the orders containing products etc.

This is all working fine, but we are trying to implement a shared shipping driver.

The shipping driver sits in it's own module so `modules/shipping/libraries/Shipping/Shipping.php`

So, I could load a library from that same folder called "Test.php" with

```
$this->load->library('shipping/test');
```

But trying to load a driver

```
$this->load->driver('shipping/shipping')
```

results in

> Unable to load the requested class: shipping

Looking through the HMVC components it appears to have a override for loading the libraries, but not the drivers, how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

myabe the problem is in case-sensitive folder & file names.

Change to

```
modules/shipping/libraries/shipping/shipping.php
```

and try loading your library.

```
$this->load->library('shipping/shipping');
```

Note : Your class name must be `Shipping` inside shipping.php